# Redux useDispatch Hook on click event of nodeListOf<HTMLElement>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a component that renders a grid. I'm trying to count the moves made (onclick of each grid box).

[image]

But when I include dispatch on the eventListener it returns an error. The moveCharacter function is supposed to move the character around those boxes and its working well. I just need a way to be able to count the moves made (onclick of each box) and store in general state to use in another component.

```
function GridBoxes():JSX.Element{
    
    const gridValue: number = useSelector<IStateProps, IStateProps["grid"]>((state)=> state.grid);
    const totalMoves: number = useSelector<IStateProps, IStateProps["totalMoves"]>((state)=> state.totalMoves);
    const history = useHistory();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    
    useEffect(()=>{
        const boxElements = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

        boxElements.forEach(element => {
            
            element.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
                
                moveCharacter(element.id, getCharacterPosition(boxElements));
                
                dispatch({type: "COUNT_MOVES", totalMoves: totalMoves + 1});
                console.log("moves");
            });
        });

        
    });
    
    useEffect(()=> {
        

        let t = setInterval(()=> {
            const timeSpent = document.getElementById("time-spent");
            const indicator = document.getElementById("indicator");
            
            let countDown = Number(timeSpent?.innerHTML);
            countDown = countDown - 1;
            
            let timeTakenPercent = ((gridValue*3) - countDown) / (gridValue*3) * 100;

            dispatch({type:"SET_TIME", payload: (gridValue*3)-countDown});

            
            (indicator as any).style.width = timeTakenPercent+"%";
            (timeSpent as any).innerHTML = countDown.toString().length < 2 ? countDown.toString().padStart(2,"0") : countDown;
        
            if(countDown < 1){
                clearInterval(t);
                history.push("/over");
                play("https://freesound.org/data/previews/175/175409_1326576-lq.mp3"); 
            }
        }, 1000);
    });

    
    const [emptyBox, characterBox, foodBox]: string[] = ['<div  class="box"></div>',`<div class="box"><img src=${assets.character} /></div>`, `<div class="box"><img src=${assets.food} /></div>`];
    const generatedGrids: string[][] = gridPattern({grid: gridValue, box:emptyBox, character: characterBox, food: foodBox});


    return (
        <>
            {generatedGrids.map((box, i)=> {
                box = setElementId(box,i);
                
                return <div key={i} className="col">{ReactHtmlParser(box.join(" "))}</div>;   
            })}
        </>
    );
}


export default GridBoxes;
```

Error gotten

[image]

Comment: might help to share WHICH error you get ;)

Comment: @phry Please see the error on the edited post.

Answer (score 2):

The error does not really come from Redux, but from some manual DOM manipulation you are doing.

Your `dispatch` call only surfaces it: when calling `dispatch`, redux state will change which will trigger a React rerender - while you are manually fiddling around with the DOM and the two things collide.

My question is: why do you do all this? The whole point of React is that is builds the DOM for you and attaches event handlers for you. At no point should you be using something like `react-html-parser`, manually concatenate html strings, manually call `addEventListener`, modify `innerHTML`, `style` or anything else on DOM elements.

Let React build your DOM for you and this error will go away.

Comment: Thanks, I'll refactor the code. I wrote it originally in vanilla Javascript, was trying to implement it with React

Comment: Honestly, at this point I don't think you need Redux yet. Just use React local component state in your parent component and pass down stuff by props. You can add Redux later if you want to give it a try, but right now you're adding a lot moving parts at once.

Comment: okay, I thought so too. But there're many components to pass value to, reason i opted for redux